# Hibernate and CRUDRepository Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and Spring boot. I understand that hibernate is ORM tool so that you can map objects to database and just use save() to save obj into the database automatically. In Spring Boot, I would do something like

```
public interface CourseRepository extends CrudRepository<Course, String>{
}
```

and somehow I will get all the CRUD operations like save and findAll etc.

From another tutorial of hibernate, it says that session is required to save the object to the database. However, I don't see any form of sessionfactory or session being implemented in Spring boot and I am still able to do the save and findAll operations etc.

How is this happening and what relations does this have with hibernate?
Where exactly should I start to find out more about hibernate, stuff like @OneToMany and basically understand the details of the whole application to database operations in spring boot? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot takes care of all the session management. Refer to this question for better understanding:

[Spring Boot & Spring Data: how are Hibernate Sessions managed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709976/spring-boot-spring-data-how-are-hibernate-sessions-managed)

Answer (score -2):

there are two things crudRepository and sessionFactory. try to find out difference between them and also try to read what is JPA and Hibernate.