# JPA - Java Spring - update an entry - edit a user

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am very new to JPA - I have this look up that will find the user on the login table.. now if I recieve new information like the user has changed their password, how do I update the entry?

---

so I find the user - lets say via their email address.

```
TblLogin acc = tblLoginRepository.findByEmail(email);
```

I've seen methods invoking "getTransaction()"

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/update

so something like this?

```
  tblLoginRepository.getTransaction().begin();
  acc.setPassword("test2");
  tblLoginRepository.getTransaction().commit();
```

but then do I just do something like this - and that is it?

```
   TblLogin acc = tblLoginRepository.findByEmail(email);
   acc.setPassword("newpassword");
```

^ and that is that - nothing else - entry is updated?

for when the user registers -- I do a saveAndFlush? I don't have to do anything else for the editing of an entry?

```
        TblLogin newAcc = tblLoginRepository.saveAndFlush(new TblLogin(
                    email,
                    password,
                    pin
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is heavy usage of terminology when using JPA. You should have a basic understanding of the basic parts like `Entity, EntityManager, Session, Transaction` etc. The [getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/) would help you. Using for example the`@Transactional` makes sure that a decorated method with this annotation is running in a transaction.

You should also check out [spring-boot-hibernate-session-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709976/spring-boot-spring-data-how-are-hibernate-sessions-managed).
Using the spring-boot's repository, you could have something like:

```
TblLogin acc = tblLoginRepository.findByEmail(email);
acc.setPassword("newpassword");
tblLoginRepository.save(acc);
```

The implementation of the above mentioned `save()` looks like:

```
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Next step would be to learn the difference between `em.persist()` and `em.flush()` as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275111/correct-use-of-flush-in-jpa-hibernate).

I hope that this answer would help you!